# Offline Spanish voice recognition: "no connection for speech input (E4)"

Tags: languages, offline, voice-recognition, google-translate

I am trying to set up a Google Nexus 7 (kitkat) and a Samsung Note 2 (jellybean) for offline English-Spanish Translation using the Google Translate app. Both devices are usually set to UK English. On each device, I have downloaded the offline spanish translation data, and that works fine in the translate app in flight mode. I have also downloaded text-to-speech data in English and Spanish, and that will output audio in both languages from the translate app in flight mode.

I have `google voice typing` set as a generic input method on each device, and I have downloaded the Espanol (Espana) Offline speech recognition pack for google voice typing. `Choose Input languages` is set to `automatic`, although changing it to English and Spanish makes no difference.

In the Google translate app, when I touch to recognise a voice in English, it works fine.

When I touch to recognise a voice in Spanish, in flight mode, on either device, I see the message,

```
No Connection for speech input (E4)
```

Spanish voice input works when not in flight mode. Can I make the app recognise Spanish voice offline? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Five minutes later... It's the setting in the Google Translate app. `Settings` - `speech input` - `Spanish` was set to `Default Dialect`. I set it to `Spanish (Spain)` and voice input now works on both devices in Spanish in Flight mode.

It would be be nice if Android was a bit less picky when it came to missing language data, like web pages work with fallback fonts. But, it works, quite well, and it's free!

Comment: More info >>> Turns out ONLY Spanish (Spain) will work in offline mode. In reading the first answer, I thought it just needed to be changed to not be 'default', so I couldn't figure out why Spanish (Mexico) wasn't working. When I changed it to Spain, all was OK. I'd like to know how Google expects anyone to know this?!?

Comment: Worked for me too. But not 100%. Not the Voice